# parsing JSON using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to parse a simple JSON file. I'm very new to javascript, JSON, and jquery. I'd like to extract the information in the JSON file so that I can plot it later using protovis. My JSON is well formed, and validates in the [JSON lint](http://www.jsonlint.com/).

I'm trying to accomplish this by parsing the JSON object's responseText, like this:

```
var json = $.getJSON("week_13.json").responseText;
var week13 = $.parseJSON(json);
```

in the hope that week13 is something I can access. Just to note, I'm not trying to use a callback function in the `$.getJSON` call as I'd like to simply have access to the variables so that I can plot them later.

I'm using Chrome, and its console, to try and figure out what's going on. In this code the variable `json` seems to be an empty string. However, if I write in the javascript console in Chrome:

```
var json = $.getJSON("week_13.json");
```

`json` is an `XMLHttpRequest` object and its `responseText` attribute is a big string containing my JSON.

```
var text = json.responseText;
```

is a nice string and then if I call jquery's parser

```
var data = $.parseJSON(text);
```

then `data` is now the object I desired. However, if I copy and paste my original two lines into the console I have no luck, and if I use the expanded version froming the `json`, `text` and `data` variables in my original webpage it doesn't work:

```
var json = $.getJSON("week_13.json");
var text = json.responseText;
var data = $.parseJSON(json);
```

In this case `text` is an empty string.

I'm totally confused. If anyone could let me know what I'm doing wrong and give some pointers as to how to make this work, I'd be very happy! Please let me know if any other information as to how I'm going about this is required to answer the question!

Comment: you can use firebug and watch how the data is coming back , use firebug net panel , some times you have do json[0] or etc....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` is asynchronous.  You need to supply a callback function to process the result. See the [API doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for examples of callback functions.

If you really need your call to be synchronous (it will block the browser while you wait for the result), then you can do this instead:

```
var url = "week_13.json"
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url, 
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).responseText
    );
```

Comment: Brilliant! So the reason my page isn't working is because the ajax call hasn't finished, so the json object is empty when the parser is called. Whereas if I do it in a console, the ajax call has finished by the time I type out the next line. Thanks so much!

Comment: Exactly.  Glad I could assist you. Don't forget to hit the check mark next to my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

On $.getJSON you don't need to call parseJSON when using the full parameter. I use it like that:

```
 $.getJSON('myjson.json', null, function (json_object) {
      // here it is already a json_object
      alert(json_object.text);
   });
```

The $.getJSON already parse the responseText into JSON object.

Comment: But how do I get the variable json_object "out of" the callback function? At the moment it seems to be stuck in the scope of the callback function, and I have no idea how to use the data in the JSON object elsewhere in my program (I'm trying to plot it).

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` function makes all the calls `asynchronously` by  default, therefore this function does not return anything. though there is a parameter of this function which takes a `callback` and returns the data to the callback function. see the example below.

The other problem to sync the program flow could be resolved by stopping all your functionality before making the call to `getJSON`, and then start the work again when you receive data in the callback.

You can also use global variable to hold the `json` and use anywhere in the program.

```
var json = null; // the global variable to store json returned from file

// stop all your work here. 
// I mean do not perform any more actions here.

// make an ajax call to get the json data
$.getJSON('week_13.json', function (jsonData) {

    // assign the data to global json variable.
    json = jsonData;


    // now call your other function to manipulate json
    // now resume your work here, 
    // and perform other actions which are dependent on json.

});
```